# Vue.js v-show directive reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div with a `v-show` and a `v-for` directive rending into my template.

Since I need to show/hide per index key, I am passing the index inside the `v-show` function, which forces me to write a a method function, rather than a computed function.

My question is that at a certain point, I would like to use Vue to show the hidden divs reactively, without re-rendering, how would I accomplish that?

#### Template

```html
<div
    v-for="(file,index) in cluster.files"
    v-show="showPartialFiles(index)"
    v-bind:key="index"
>
```

#### Script

```
methods: {
            showPartialFiles: function(index){
                if (index <= this.$store.state.numberOfAssignmentCutoff - 1)
                return true;
            },
    }
```

p.s.
I have no problem writing in vanilla/JQuery to accomplish this yet I want to build this with Vue into the Vue object for extensibility and reusability in the future.

Many thanks, Bud.

Comment: What is the current challenge/ error you are facing? This code looks like it should work fine as long as the `file` variable is guaranteed to be reactive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a computed property for that, then the v-show will react to changes in the store;

```
computed: {
    showPartialFiles() {
        return (index) => {
            return index <= this.$store.state.numberOfAssignmentCutoff - 1
        }
    }
}
```